# Questions on Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am in trouble with two problems. Thank you for your positive answer.

1. Is the incidence matrix of a directed graph totally unimodular?
2. Let bipartite graph without isolated vertices. Dose the maximum cardinality of a stable set equal the minuimum cardinality of an edge cover?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- For the first question, *incidence* matrix yes (e.g. see [this pdf](http://www2.math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Mathematik/AG-Eisenbrand/teaching/opt2006/19-12.pdf)). Do not confuse with *adjacency* matrix, for example $$\det\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{array} \right] = 2.$$
- For the second question, see the [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) and consider the complements.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Let $S$ be a the set of all matrix such that every row is of the form $(0,...,0,1,1,...,1,0,....,0)$. Is S totally unimodular? Thank you.

Comment: @user129982 Yes, it is called "consecutive-ones property", and even [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) mentions it.

Comment: How can prove this? I tried but didnot success

Comment: @user129982 I've made it a Q&A [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/689661/26306).