# Total unimodularity of matrix with consecutive ones property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix has the consecutive ones property (often abbreviated C1P) if
its every row (or column, for column-oriented C1P) is of the form $(0,\ldots,0,1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0)$.

There is a theorem which says that any such matrix is [totally unimodular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity), i.e. its every square submatrix has determinant $-1$, $0$ or $1$.

Naturally, this also holds if we could permute and/or transpose the matrix into one with consecutive ones property, however, how do I prove the theorem?

**Context:** The question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682248/questions-on-grap-theory/682276#comment1443508_682276), but the answer was to long for a comment, and didn't fit as edit into the original post.

Comment: @K.C.Wu Not really. It's a naming convention, I'm assuming here row-oriented consecutive ones property, and the proof for the column-oriented version is similar (or you can work with transposed matrix).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know who is the original author of this proof, but I have seen it more than one time.

**Idea:**

The general idea is that, for any sequence of the form $$(0,0,\ldots,0,1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0),$$ the sequence of differences is $$(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots,0,-1,0,0,\ldots,0),$$ that is, it contains at most two entries, one $1$ and one $-1$. Hence, we can manipulate any submatrix to make it simpler and calculate its determinant.

**Proof:**

Let's assume that the matrix has row-oriented consecutive ones property (for column-oriented version work with transposed matrix). Let $A$ be any square submatrix; of course, it also has the consecutive ones property.

Define matrix $B$ by

$$
b_{r,c} =
\begin{cases}
a_{r,c} - a_{r,c+1} & \text{ for }c+1 \leq \mathrm{columns}(A), \\
a_{r,c} & \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

By C1P, the matrix $B$ has in each row at most two entries. There are three cases:

- If some row has no non-zero entries, the determinant is zero.
- If some row has one non-zero entry, we could perform [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along that row and consider further the only minor whose coefficient is non-zero.
- After all the expansions, all the rows left (if there are any) has exactly two non-zero entries, one $1$ and one $-1$. Call this matrix $B'$ and observe that $$B' \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{array}\right],$$ in other words, $B'$ is singular and its determinant is zero.

Hence, the determinant of $B$ is in $\{-1,0,1\}$, and by its definition, the determinant of $A$ is also in $\{-1,0,1\}$. However, $A$ was any square submatrix, therefore, we have proved the total unimodularity of the original matrix.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: What do we do in the second case where some row has exactly one non-zero entry, do we use induction? if yes then how do we apply the induction hypothesis or decide what the induction hypothesis should be for the proof to go through?