# Prove this matrix is or is not totally unimodular

Tags: computational-mathematics, total-unimodularity

Is there an easy way to show or disprove the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&  0&  0&1 &0 &0
\\0&0&1&1&0&1&0
\\0&0&0&0&1&1&1
\\1&   0&  0&0&1& 0&0
\\0&1&0&0&1& 0&0
\\0&0&1&0&0&1&0
\\0&0&0&1&0&1&0
\\0&0&0&0&1&0&1
\\0&0&0&0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$

is totally unimodular?

If you look at the matrix, almost all the rows have two non-zero entries and only $1/3$rd of the rows have three non-zero entries. So $2/3$rd of the matrix is directly totally unimodular. It is the rows with three non-zero entries which seem a little tricky.

Comment: The matrix isn't large. Just check all the square submatrices and see if any have determinant not $0,1,-1.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145296/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-turbo).

Comment: @IonzaIeggiera That is not for Total unimodularity but only unimodularity.

Comment: @Turbo Ah, yes.  I had conflated the latter concept with the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder the rows so that the columns satisfy the consecutive ones property:

```
0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   1   0   0   1   0
0   0   1   1   0   1   0
0   0   0   1   0   1   0
```

Comment: I accepted but what is the consecutive ones property?

Comment: It means that all the ones in each column  appear consecutively, and it is a well-known sufficient condition for TU.

Comment: See a proof of the "consecutive ones" property [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689662/305862).