# Find if a XOR game collapses to a certain state regardless of the input

Tags: number-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

A state is a binary sequence made up of 4 bits.

Initially, there's a random and unknown state. You can choose to XOR the state with any other state. Then, the state is randomly permuted in a circular manner. This process can repeat multiple times. Can you guarantee to reach the $(0,0,0,0)$ state regardless of the initial state?

The source of the problem is unknown and I have tried to observe the behavior on different inputs, but I don't have anything specific to post.

Comment: Somewhat [similar](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89245/is-fibonacci-xor-rotate-one-way-ish)

Comment: If you reach $\ (0,0,0,0)\ $ do you get notified as soon as you've done so?  If so, then yes, I think  you can guarantee to annihilate the state within a fixed finite number of moves.

Comment: Yes, you are notified you've done so. How do you prove you can do it within a fixed number of moves?

Comment: When you say it is randomly permuted, do you mean that it can be permuted by 1-shift, or 2 shifts, or 3-shifts but not stay still (0-shift) ?

Comment: In you last comment, when you say "a *fixed* number of moves" you surely mean a "*finite* number of moves", isn't it ?

Comment: The state can remain the same after being permuted. And yes, in a finite number of moves.

Comment: When you say "You can choose to XOR the state s with any other state $s_1$", do we have a modification : new s = XOR$(\text{old } s, s_1)$ or does $s$ remains the same ?

Comment: @Jean Marie If I've understood the question correctly, I've proved that you can guarantee to annihilate the state within $16$ moves.  I've written up the  proof, but the question has now been closed, so I can't post it.

Comment: @lonza leggiera It's a pity ! I would be so interested ! I incitate you to create a "follow on" question of your own, stating the problem with a short reference to the initial question and all at once answering your question. This has been done rather frequently. Meanwhile, feel free to make a little "Edit" in my answer (with your own signature) explaining only the principle of your solution and sending readers to your "follow on" question. In any case, let me know.

Comment: @lonza leggiera Here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/689661/305862) (interesting in its own) among many of a "Q&A".

Comment: @Jean Marie Here are the sixteen sequences to successively XOR to whatever state you've reached :$$1.\ 0000\\2.\ 1111\\3.\ 0101\\4.\ 1111\\5.\ 0011\\6.\ 1111\\7.\ 0101\\8.\ 1111\\9.\ 0001\\10.\ 1111\\11.\ 0101\\12.\ 1111\\13.\ 0011\\14.\ 1111\\15.\ 0101\\16.\ 1111\ .$$ I'm assuming here that if $\ S\ $ is the current state, $\ M\ $ is the sequence XORed onto it, and $\ S\oplus M\ne0000\ $, then next state will be a random circular shift of $\ S\oplus M\ $.

Comment: @lonza leggiera I just checked : it works wonderfully : I have observed on a large scale simulation that random variable S (stopping time) is uniformly distributed on [1,16] giving E(S)=8.5. *Please* write this "Q&A" where you will explain how you have had the idea of this sequence.

Comment: @lonza leggiera In fact, it also works (in at most 16 steps) for any shuffle of the rows of your $16 \times 4$ array of the form $n \in [0,15] \to a∗n \in [0,15]$ (where $a$ is any odd number ; please note that I use here a line numbering beginning at $0$).

Comment: @lonza leggiera Thank you !

Comment: @Jean Marie I finally bothered following all the links to the origin of the problem. It's a particular case (with $N=4$) of question $7$ (about the same problem for a general $N$) of the senior A-level Tournament of the Towns paper of autumn 2009, which can be found at this link: http://www.math.toronto.edu/oz/turgor/archives/TT2009F_SAproblems.pdf.  The solution can be found on the solution sheet at this link: http://www.math.toronto.edu/oz/turgor/archives/TT2009F_SAsolutions.pdf.

Comment: As is typical with this sort of puzzle the thought processes I went through in deriving the above solution were rather convoluted, and I don't even remember most of them. My original proof that the above solution worked was an unenlightening collection of casework. On cleaning it up, however, I found a nice proof based on the lengths of the orbits of the group of circular shifts acting on the sequences.  A nice question would be whether this proof can be generalise to cover the case of arbitrary $N=2^n$, which I am as yet unsure of.  When I can find the time I'll write it up as a new question.

Comment: @Jean Marie [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682142/can-this-solution-be-generalised-from-n-4-to-n-2r) my write-up of the question. I now think I can generalise the solution to one for any $\ N=2^r\ $.